# Пример простого вэб-сервиса, по получению геолокации по ip через протокол soap. PHP

Tags: php, soap, геолокация

Ребят помогите, может кто знает где посмотреть как это работает. Нужен пример рабочего сервиса определения геолокации  по ip  через протокол soap, написанный на php. Гуглится чет вообще с трудом.

Comment: А Soap ещё жив?!

Comment: @AlexeyTen да вроде как, задание просто такое именно с soap надо сделать

Comment: @EvgenyPivovarov напишите обертку JSON => XML, XML => JSON на Ipdata.co если принципиально. Задание? Может стоит обсудить с тем кто его ставит?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать [Ipdata.co](https://Ipdata.co). Является быстрым, высокодоступным IP Geolocation API с надежной производительностью.

Это чрезвычайно масштабируемая система с 10 конечными точками по всему миру, каждая из которых способна обрабатывать> 10 000 запросов в секунду!

В качестве альтернативы - [Geo IP Location](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php).

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую как альтернативу, но надо почему то soap использовать